# Error with quotes in search query

Tags: c#, mysql

I am displaying a report using an SQL query. In this report the user can search by customer. So I created a search function. The searchfield is the customer (selected from a dropdownlist) and the search terms is what the user enters into a textbox to search:

```
StringBuilder SQL = new StringBuilder(SearchSQL);
if (SearchFieldKey != null && SearchFieldKey.Length > 0)
{
  if (SearchTerms != null)
  {
    SQL.Append(" HAVING ");
    for (int i = 0; i < SearchFieldKey.Length; i++)
    {
      if (SearchFields.ContainsKey(SearchFieldKey[i]))
      {
        SQL.Append(SearchFields[SearchFieldKey[i]] + " LIKE ?parameter" + i.ToString());
        param.Add(new MySqlParameter("parameter" + i.ToString(),
          "%" + SearchTerms[i] + "%"));

        if (i != SearchFieldKey.Length - 1)
          SQL.Append(" OR ");
      }
      else
        throw new Exception("Error: Attempted to search on invalid field. Check SearchFields Argument.");
    }
  }
}

SQL.Append(" '); ");
SQL.Append ("prepare stmt from @sql; execute stmt; deallocate prepare stmt;");
```

This function adds the HAVING query to the end of the query displaying the report (SearchSQL). The problem is with the quotes near LIKE. The end of the query returns this:

```
WHERE c.Company_ID = ', 135,
' GROUP BY c.ID  HAVING c.Name LIKE "%TEST%" ');
```

But because the quote was at the end of the statement it couldn't read the parameter being passed into it so I was getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?parameter0' at line 23

So I need the query to be like this:

```
WHERE c.Company_ID = ', 135,
' GROUP BY c.ID HAVING c.Name LIKE', "%TEST%" );
```

See the quote has moved to after the LIKE and a comma has been added. This is what I need to do to make the query work. But when I try do this in my current code it causes an error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%TEST%' at line 23

So what do I need to do in the search function?

I pasted the query into MySQL Workbench so its clearer to see whats happening.

The problem is here:

[image]

See how LIKE "%PRL%" is all green because it is included in the quotes so it wasn't reading the parameter.

Now see how it should be:

[image]

Closing the quote after the like, the parameter can now be read. So the problem is with my code. What do I need to change so get this to work?

Here is full SearchSQL function:

```
private static string SearchSQL
{
  get
  {
    return @"SET group_concat_max_len=10000000;
             set @sql = null;
             select group_concat(distinct
               concat('MAX(CASE WHEN pt.Code = ''', 
                             pt.Code ,
                           ''' THEN jp.AdvisedQty ELSE 0 END) AS `',
                           pt.Code, '`')
                     ) into @sql
                                                                                            FROM customer c
                 LEFT JOIN job_address ja ON c.AccountCode = ja.Code AND c.Company_ID = ja.Company_ID
                 JOIN  AddressType jat ON ja.AddressType = jat.ID and jat.Description = 'Debtor'
                 LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON ja.JobID = jn.ID
                 LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON ja.JobID = jp.ID
                 LEFT JOIN piecestype pt on jp.TypeID = pt.ID
                 WHERE c.Company_ID = ?compid;

                 set @sql = concat('select c.Name, COUNT(distinct jn.ID) as Jobs,
                   SUM((select COUNT(ID) from jobstat where Status = ''DEL'' AND JobID = jn.ID)) as Delivered,
                  SUM((select COUNT(ID) from jobstat where Status = ''POD'' AND JobID = jn.ID)) as POD,
                  (select COUNT(job_debriefs.ID) from job_debriefs WHERE JobID = jn.JobNo) as Debriefs,
                  sum(jn.OutTurn) as Outturn,
                  SUM(jn.ActualWeight) as GrossWt,
                  SUM(jn.CBM) as CBM,
                  jn.Department,
                  (SELECT Name FROM job_address WHERE AddressType =3 AND JobID = jn.ID) as CollectName,
                  (SELECT Name FROM job_address WHERE AddressType =2 AND JobID = jn.ID) as DeliverName,
                  ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM customer c
                   LEFT JOIN job_address ja ON c.AccountCode = ja.Code AND c.Company_ID = ja.Company_ID
                   JOIN  AddressType jat ON ja.AddressType = jat.ID and jat.Description = ''Debtor''
                   LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON ja.JobID = jn.ID
                   LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON ja.JobID = jp.ID
                   LEFT JOIN piecestype pt on jp.TypeID = pt.ID
                   WHERE c.Company_ID = ', ?compid,
                    ' GROUP BY c.ID";
  }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you want and what is the error. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: Have you tried `"'%TEST%'"`? Take note of the single-quote after opening and before closing double-quotes.

Comment: @OrelEraki I have updated the question. I hope it is clearer now what I am trying to do

Comment: @JoelLegaspiEnriquez Yes I have but adding the single quotes still causes the same error

Comment: @user123456789, You will need to publish the full code that generate the `SQL Query` from scratch.

Comment: @OrelEraki you want me to show the code for `SearchSQL`?

Comment: @user123456789, We need the complete code that generate it from the start of the `SELECT`.

Comment: @OrelEraki I added the code to my question

Comment: I formatted your code to something at least resembling reasonable to read. Your query will not work in the other form either, there's an opening ' but no closing one. Are the values really in quotes? The database seems to be quite unnormalized and will cause headache now and in the future. Also MySQL Workbench colorization has nothing to do with correctness of the query. As you can see there are still errors with the query, if you just execute it.

Comment: Don't use string concatenation, use parameterized queries. If your query is that complex, create a view or stored procedure instead. If you need to execute two or more statements, a stored procedure is the only viable option. This isn't a C# problem, it's about writing good SQL code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to this problem:

```
 StringBuilder SQL = new StringBuilder(SearchSQL);
            if (SearchFieldKey != null && SearchFieldKey.Length > 0)
            {
                if (SearchTerms != null)
                {
                    SQL.Append(" HAVING ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < SearchFieldKey.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (SearchFields.ContainsKey(SearchFieldKey[i]))
                        {

                            SQL.Append(SearchFields[SearchFieldKey[i]] + " LIKE ', ?parameter" + i.ToString());
                            param.Add(new MySqlParameter("parameter" + i.ToString(), "\'%" + SearchTerms[i] + "%\'"));

                            if (i != SearchFieldKey.Length - 1)
                                SQL.Append("', OR ");

                        }
                        else
                            throw new Exception("Error: Attempted to search on invalid field. Check SearchFields Argument.");
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                SQL.Append("'");
            }

            SQL.Append("); ");
            SQL.Append ("prepare stmt from @sql; execute stmt; deallocate prepare stmt;");
```

I was missing a space after LIKE and I added an else to close the quote